What parts of a URL count toward SharePoint path length?
Plenty of articles tell me that when calculating a the length of a SharePoint path, I ignore the server protocol and name, and start with (in the case of a business site) /sites. Those articles also often mention that parameters are not counted toward path length.
However, it is difficult to know quite how to apply this advice to a real-life SharePoint URL, and googling the issue has provided me either with conflicting information or with articles that sort of skate over the matter without clarifying it.
In the browser URL shown here (decoded, for easier reading):
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/Shared Documents/Forms/
AllItems.aspx?FolderCTID=0x012000283F45AAD7B07547B1F52BBDDDE6FF93&id=/sites
/SiteName/Shared Documents/FolderName/Image.png

…the /sites/SiteName/Shared Documents part appears twice, with the SharePoint parameters (query string?) between them. My question is this:
My question is this:Should I count the length of my file path beginning from the start of the first instance of /sites, or from the second?

When calculating the length of a SharePoint path, you should start counting from the first instance of /sites, not the second. The URL in your example contains query parameters (everything after ?), and these parameters should not be counted toward the path length.
Start counting from the first instance of /sites in your path and exclude the query string parameters. The presence of the same path in the query string does not affect the actual path length calculation.
Given your URL, the path you should count the length for is:
/sites/SiteName/Shared Documents/FolderName/Image.png

Ignore the query string (everything after ?) and the server name (before /sites).
See an explanation here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/maxpath-limits-in-sharepoint-url/5b24d9b0-8e88-4e1c-94e0-d26121c30a47
